# How can I create a right click menu item to manipulate a junction point?

Tags: windows-7, shell-extensions, junction

As I am using a SSD but it is limited in size I want to be able to use junction points to remap files and directories to my HDD, this would work ideal if I could create a shell extension for it that does this.

The ideal behavior would be to right click a directory or junction point and have an option
"Manipulate junction point" in which I can perform the following actions:

- **Create:** For a directory, move the directory to a location I specify and replace it by a junction point.
  **(Dir) C:\Example** turns into **(JP) C:\Example --> D:\Example**
- **Swap:** For a junction point, I want to swap the junction point with its location.
  **(JP) C:\Example --> (Dir) D:\Example** turns into **(Dir) C:\Example <-- (JP) D:\Example**

  This means it would remove the junction point, move the data and place a reverse junction point.
- **Remove:** For a junction point, I want to remove it and move the directory back.
  **(JP) C:\Example --> (Dir) D:\Example** turns into **(Dir) C:\Example**

My most important questions:

- What approach should I take to do this? Script? Bash? Executable?
- How do I create the menu entry?

Less important questions:

- Does there exist such a solution already?
- Are there better commands or API calls for checking and manipulating junction points?

I already know of Microsoft's `mklink` and Sysinternals `junction`.

Comment: Just to let it out - I can't really think of a situation (or recognize the one you cited) where doing this is a necessity, meaning I'd try other approaches to solve the broader issue, whatever it is. Why linking SSD files to the HDD?

Comment: Because not everything fits on the SSD, so I have to move things that do not require to be fast to my HDD without breaking anything... I don't want a workaround, I want a solution.

Comment: We've made a blog post about [maximizing the lifetime of your SSD](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/05/10/maximizing-the-lifetime-of-your-ssd/).

Comment: related: http://superuser.com/questions/95862/what-directories-in-a-windows-7-ssd-install-would-you-link-junction-to-an-hdd

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since you asked if such solutions exist already, have you taken a look at [Junction Link Magic](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Miscellaneous/Junction-Link-Magic.shtml) or [Link Shell Extension](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html)?

Junction Link Magic allows creation, modification, and removal of junction points. It is freeware, and does support Windows 7.

Link Shell Extension also provides the same functionality, and is also freeware. It also supports Windows 7.

**UPDATE**: The [original site](http://www.rekenwonder.com/linkmagic.htm) for Junction Link Magic is 404'ing now. I've substituted a Softpedia link for those who still want to install JLM.

Comment: For some reason, I vaguely remember @TomWij mentioning these software in a comment on a hardlink/junction point-related question here on SU. I just can't find the *actual* question at the moment.

Comment: Exactly, but I want the best way to do it, I didn't know of the extension though, I'm checking it out now...

Comment: It indeeds makes it easier to work with junction points, I'll use this for the moment being and I will leave this open waiting for a better solution... I wish the source code was available so I could remove the text it adds to the directory name and to remove the options I will never use.

Comment: Just to add: you've probably found these already, but here's a couple of links off CodeProject (with source) related to junction points: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/winsdk/junctionpoints.aspx and http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista/ReparsePointID.aspx

Comment: Seems interesting, maybe I either spent a bounty here or decide to spent some time on research and implementation one of these days...

Comment: After using it for some time, this seems to work just fine. I won't do the swapping that much so I can do the steps manually...

Answer (score 2):

I just use `MKLINK` which is built into Windows 7. You'll end up writing batch files I guess, but it's not hard to use.